# How to set addEventListener on the autocomplete input and provide several source callbacks and use them one by one

Tags: javascript, input, callback, fetch-api

I'm trying to set `addEventListener` on input, when it will be changing I want to call function with fetch API.
I have autocomplete input with city-names, my aim is to get info by selected city-name
and secondly, maybe someone knows how to optimize this code with calling callbacks and use them one by one until the result of callback return not empty array.

Now I have input with city-names (got by API for JSON) but console shows me that input-value is undefined when I choose some city.

I have js file:

```js
let cities = document.querySelector("#languageList");
let cityInfoContainer = document.querySelector(".cityInfoContainer");
let input = document.querySelector("#txtAutoComplete");



  fetch("https://katehrybkova.github.io/CItiesFilter/src/analytics/fixtures/cities.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
     data.map(el=>cities.innerHTML += `<option value=${el.city}>`)
  })
  .catch(err => { throw err });
  

  let getCityInfo = (cityName) => fetch(`https://katehrybkova.github.io/CItiesFilter/src/analytics/fixtures/data/${cityName.toLowerCase()}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    data.map(city => city.map(el=>cityInfoContainer.innerHTML += `<p> ${el.year}</p>`))
  })
  .catch(err => { throw err });
  
  input.addEventListener("change", getCityInfo(this.value))
```

and HTML

```html
<body>
    <header></header>
    <main class="cityInfo">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="languageList" />
            <datalist id="languageList">
            </datalist>
        </form>
        <div class="cityInfoContainer"></div>

    </main>
    <footer></footer>
    <script src="./dist/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use Promises (or async-await)
2. You forgot the **.json** from the end of your City Info API request
3. **.map()** returns a new Array. You needed **.forEach()** for this function
4. Only one **.forEach()** was needed (so not a map in a map), as the array was only one level deep

```js
let cities = document.querySelector("#languageList");
let cityInfoContainer = document.querySelector(".cityInfoContainer");
let input = document.querySelector("#txtAutoComplete");

getCityNames()
  .then(data => {
    data.map(el => cities.innerHTML += `<option value=${el.city}>`)
  })

input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  getCityInfo(this.value)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      // this clears the area for the new city selected
      if (cityInfoContainer.innerHTML !== '') {
        cityInfoContainer.innerHTML = ''
      }
      data.forEach(city => cityInfoContainer.innerHTML += `<p> ${city.year} ${city.population}</p>`)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('err', err)
    })
})

function getCityNames() {
  return new Promise((resolve, rejecet) => {
    fetch("https://katehrybkova.github.io/CItiesFilter/src/analytics/fixtures/cities.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        resolve(data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      });
  })
}

function getCityInfo(cityName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(`https://katehrybkova.github.io/CItiesFilter/src/analytics/fixtures/data/${cityName.toLowerCase()}.json`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        resolve(data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      });
  })
}
```

```html
<main class="cityInfo">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="languageList" />
    <datalist id="languageList">
            </datalist>
  </form>
  <div class="cityInfoContainer"></div>

</main>
```

As for calling them one-by-one, until all the info is downloaded:

```js
let cities = document.querySelector("#languageList");
let cityInfoContainer = document.querySelector(".cityInfoContainer");
let input = document.querySelector("#txtAutoComplete");

// adding an array that will hold all the cities' names
let cityNameArr = []

getCityNames()
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(el => cities.innerHTML += `<option value=${el.city}>`)
    return data.map(el => {
      return {
        cName: el.city
      }
    })
  })
  .then(cityNames => {
    return cityNames.map(el => {
      return {
        cName: el.cName,
        cInfo: getCityInfo(el.cName)
      }
    })
  })
  .then(city => {
    console.log(city) // expected to see "cInfo: Promise" - until it's resolved
  })



input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  getCityInfo(this.value)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      // this clears the area for the new city selected
      if (cityInfoContainer.innerHTML !== '') {
        cityInfoContainer.innerHTML = ''
      }
      data.forEach(city => cityInfoContainer.innerHTML += `<p> ${city.year} ${city.population}</p>`)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('err', err)
    })
})

function getCityNames() {
  return new Promise((resolve, rejecet) => {
    fetch("https://katehrybkova.github.io/CItiesFilter/src/analytics/fixtures/cities.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        resolve(data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      });
  })
}

function getCityInfo(cityName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(`https://katehrybkova.github.io/CItiesFilter/src/analytics/fixtures/data/${cityName.toLowerCase()}.json`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        resolve(data)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      });
  })
}
```

```html
<main class="cityInfo">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="languageList" />
    <datalist id="languageList">
            </datalist>
  </form>
  <div class="cityInfoContainer"></div>

</main>
```